# Binding two inputs to the same model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

[As demonstrated in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/74j8DhCPUJwNZ1ckg1rg?p=preview), I'd like to have an <input type="number"/> <input type="range"/> which both update the same `$scope` variable, as well as each other.

Right now, when I update one input the $scope variable is changed, but the value of the other scope is blanked. Do I just need to bind one with data-ng-model and use data-ng-change on the other? Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5C9Q7wq4j43hCmiViuDT) that I will be referencing. The problem is that range is a string value while number is an number value.

Instantiate a variable within your controller and write the function to handle conversion

```
$scope.data = 10;

$scope.setDataAsNumber = function() {
  $scope.data = parseInt($scope.data, 10);
}
```

Create all your elements bound to `$scope.data`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data" ng-change="setDataAsNumber()">
<br>
<input type="number" ng-model="data">
<br>
<input type="range" ng-model="data" ng-change="setDataAsNumber()">
<br>
{{ data }}
```

I have solved this using ng-change directive.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why this is, but when you change the type="number" to type="text" it works.

I found this workaround for input type="number" but seems a bit hacky:

```
$scope.$watch('MyNumber',function(number) {
  $scope.MyNumber = Number(number);
});
```

Comment: Sounds like an Angular bug. I guess I don't need spinners since I got the range.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same.  It should work without the above $watch workaround.  Interesting find.

Comment: i think its problem with type="number" itself as it expect Number but when we use range type it returns string. And why range type works fine with textbox

Comment: Range returns text and number returns numbers? That makes no sense, can range ever be made to represent not numbers?

Comment: Not sure why it would be anything but a number.  Found this:

http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/#valueAsNumber

Comment: @JustinDearing when you change value in inputtext(number) it show value's type as Number and when you use range it shows type as String. see this http://plnkr.co/edit/W5VhTe6afrsVdx9lxlOL?p=preview

Comment: @Akhlesh I understand that's whats happening, I just find the behavior unintuitive.

Comment: @Justin yeah, too good to be true I guess. Until then, javascript will be the way to go I guess.