# Multiple input elements with same ng-model within an angularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I want to create a range slider with an input field to directly type the value (like in jQM: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/slider/).

My directive looks like this:

```
app.directive("mySlider", [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            id: "@?",
            min: "@",
            max: "@",
            step: "@?",
            value: "=ngModel"
        },
        template: "" +
            "<div class='my-sliderWrap'>" +
                "<input type='number' min={{min}} max={{max}} step={{step}} value={{value}} ng-model=value>" +
                "<input type='range' min={{min}} max={{max}} step={{step}} value={{value}} ng-model=value>" +
            "</div>",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            //some logic here
        }
    }
}]);
```

Well, this works nice when I'm changing the value of the number input. The slider moves and the value attributes both are updated. As soon as I move the slider directly, both value attributes still update but the text of my number input gets cleared somehow and set to its minimum.

Have I made some mistake within the template or with the data binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, according to this answer on the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808152/2577116

Summary: It seems that the HTML5 range input does not return a number but a string. Assigning this string to the number input causes the same to clear itself, as, who would think of that, it will expect a number...

As solution we just need to convert the returned string value into a number. I do it with parseFloat() for example:

```
$scope.$watch('value',function(newValue) {
  $scope.value = parseFloat(newValue); //or Number(newValue); or parseInt(newValue);
});
```

This logic can just be inserted into the link function. Done.

Not very nice, but easy workaround.